# Python, macOS - How do I create a finder alias of a file?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I would like to be able to create an alias from directly within python in the same way that it would be created if I right clicked on the item in Finder and selected `make alias`(see image below). macOS finder aliases are proprietary file formats, and are not the same thing as either a hard link or a symbolic link. The original file that I will be making an alias of and the destination path of the newly created alias will need to be passed as variables into an argument. I would prefer to just use the POSIX path of these items.

[image: Make alias]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48862093/2650249

Comment: Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244781/what-replaces-the-now-deprecated-carbon-file-fsresolvealiasfile-in-python-on-osx